# C - how to set default values for types in C headers

Tags: c, header, types

I have some headers from a C++ background that use many pre-baked "defaults" for declared types. e.g.

```
// Header.

typedef struct
{
    float red;
    float green;
    float blue;
} RGBColor;

// Defaults.
const RGBColor kRGB_White = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
const RGBColor kRGB_Black = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
```

...

```
// Source file.

RGBColor aColor = kRGB_White;
```

Q. I need to convert these headers in to C for compatibility reasons. Is there a way to re-create these default values for a C header, preferably without changing the data structures themselves?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prevent problems with duplicate global definitions, you'll want to change the declarations of your `const` structures in the headers to:

```
extern const RGBColor kRGB_White;
extern const RGBColor kRGB_Black;
```

And place the definitions in a single .c file that gets linked in.

An alternative is to change the `const` structures to be static so it doesn't hurt when they end up in several different modules:

```
static const RGBColor kRGB_White = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
static const RGBColor kRGB_Black = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
```

This might cause the objects to show up more than once in the final linked image, but today's linkers are probably smart enough to get rid of the duplicates (I think - some testing might be in order if the structs you're doing this with are large and/or numerous).

In case you're worried about using the consts to initialize other variables, this:

```
RGBColor aColor = kRGB_White;
```

is fine in C (it seems relatively common for programmers to think that C doesn't allow this for some reason - maybe it wasn't always allowed in pre-standard C?).

Comment: I believe many people think `RGBColor aColor = kRGB_White;` is not C legal because `int foo[4] = {1,2,3,4}; int bar[4] = foo` is not legal and arrays seem to have more exposure than structs.

Comment: I would tend to recommend the `static const` approach - it makes the definition of the `const` objects available to the compiler without requiring link time cross-module optimisation.  You also cannot use `const` objects to initialise objects with static storage duration - you should also create `#define KRGB_WHITE_STATIC { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }` for that case.

Comment: Thanks all for your help. Using gcc 4.0 on OS X 10.6.6, the "static const" approach caused "duplicate symbol" errors. Sad face. And, sadder still, the redefine them as macros approach didn't work either. I think I'll have to take the advise to declare them as externs, and stick them all in a source file.  Cheers.

Comment: @SirRatty: That sounds like you don't have guards preventing multiple inclusion of your header (or have a stray `extern` declaration of the symbols somewhere).

Comment: I do have #ifdef __MY_FILE__ #endif guards in all of my headers (even #imports), and I don't use externs. So yeah, not sure what's going on there.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot move the default value declarations out of the header file, redefine them as macros:

```
// Might not be a clean solution...
#define kRGB_White {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f} 
#define kRGB_Black {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}
```

Comment: If you can guarantee C99 you could at least do `((RGBColor){1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f})` to keep people from trying something like `float f[] = kRGB_White;`. [insert disclaimer about the futility of trying to prevent people from doing stupid things via the type system instead of clear and unambiguous documentation.]

Comment: This will work as an initializer, but it will not work in assignment. Also, it will not work in lvalue context. I suppose that the OP might need these uses as well.

Comment: @AndreyT - `const` objects will not work in lvalue context either, and in C99 I believe my modified version would work in assignment.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: `const` objects will work fine in lvalue context, since they are lvalues.

Comment: +1, but perhaps you could edit your answer to include the compound literal version. And since I am at it, compound literals with `const` can be optimized better, since the compiler is allowed to fold several instances into one. This would then be `(RGBColor const){1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}`.